# Blade templating

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

Is it possible to have the master.blade.php file outside of the template files.

Example below:

```
views/
     master.blade.php
     layout/
           hello.blade.php
```

views/layout/hello.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.master)
```

I have tried the above but it cannot find the master.blade.php file. So is there a way to refer to a directory above the blade file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be

```
@extends('master')
```

the "." in the view names indicate folders.  so

```
@extends('my.long.path.to.template')
```

would be found in:

```
/views/my/long/path/to/template.blade.php
```

layouts don't have to be in a folder called `layouts`

Comment: Thanks. Been staring at the screen all day. Just noticed it as well.